# Use generated column to create another column - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a column that gets generated using `CAST(CASE WHEN A and B THEN SSS) as Name`

Now I need another column which will use the value of the column above in the same way `(CASE WHEN Name SSS THEN 123)`

Is that possible?

**UPDATE**:

Example:

I have a table with

```
Name, Age, UserCode, UserId
```

I would like to generate a table using `SELECT` which includes

```
Name, UserCode, UserName
```

- `Name`: returned from the column `Name`
- `UserCode`:

  ```
  CAST(CASE WHEN UserCode = 'A' and UserId = 'B' THEN 'SSS'
       CASE WHEN UserCode = 'C' and UserId = 'Z' THEN 'ZAZ')
  ```
- `UserName`: use the result from `UserCode`, so if `UserCode` is SSS then `UserName` become SAR123 etc...

Comment: Question is a bit ambiguous. I think we need some more details.

Comment: Okay ill try to add more details now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select *,
CASE UserCode 
     When 'SSS' Then 'SAR123'
     --When ...   --<<Put other When clauses here
END AS UserName
FROM(
     Select Name , 
            CASE WHEN UserCode = 'A' and UserId = 'B' THEN 'SSS'
                 WHEN UserCode = 'C' and UserId = 'Z' THEN 'ZAZ'
            END AS UserCode
     From Table
    ) AS K
```

Answer (score 1):

The alias of column name are obtained  after the FROM, WHERE and then SELECT clause code evaluation  .. so these alias are not available before this evalution is finished for this reason 
alias of column name are not allowed  in select or where clause  and for these clause you must rewrite the  code when need

```
select (CASE  WHEN CAST(CASE WHEN A and B THEN SSS .....) SSS THEN 123 .... )
FROM my_table  
.......
```

but alias for column name are available for ORDER BY and GROUP BY (clause that are evalueted  after the previous mentioned)

alias of coulmn can be used  in order by and group by